# Autoscroll to bottom of page, but make scroll interruptable by user

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'd like to auto-scroll to the bottom of a webpage (smoothly), but I also want users to be able to interrupt that auto-scroll if they start to manually scroll:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#container').classList.add('scroll-down');
})

document.addEventListener('mousewheel', () => {
  document.querySelector('#container').classList.remove('scroll-down');
})
```

```css
.scroll-down {
  transition: transform 6s linear;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
<div>21</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>23</div>
<div>24</div>
<div>25</div>
<div>26</div>
<div>27</div>
<div>28</div>
<div>29</div>
<div>30</div>
<div>31</div>
<div>32</div>
<div>33</div>
<div>34</div>
<div>35</div>
<div>36</div>
<div>37</div>
<div>38</div>
<div>39</div>
<div>40</div>
<div>41</div>
<div>42</div>
<div>43</div>
<div>44</div>
<div>45</div>
<div>46</div>
<div>47</div>
<div>48</div>
<div>49</div>
<div>50</div>
<div>51</div>
<div>52</div>
<div>53</div>
<div>54</div>
<div>55</div>
<div>56</div>
<div>57</div>
<div>58</div>
<div>59</div>
<div>60</div>
<div>61</div>
<div>62</div>
<div>63</div>
<div>64</div>
<div>65</div>
<div>66</div>
<div>67</div>
<div>68</div>
<div>69</div>
<div>70</div>
<div>71</div>
<div>72</div>
<div>73</div>
<div>74</div>
<div>75</div>
<div>76</div>
<div>77</div>
<div>78</div>
<div>79</div>
<div>80</div>
<div>81</div>
<div>82</div>
<div>83</div>
<div>84</div>
<div>85</div>
<div>86</div>
<div>87</div>
<div>88</div>
<div>89</div>
<div>90</div>
<div>91</div>
<div>92</div>
<div>93</div>
<div>94</div>
<div>95</div>
<div>96</div>
<div>97</div>
<div>98</div>
<div>99</div>
<div>100</div>
</div>
```

I'm after something like the above, but removing the scroll-down class right now removes the transform entirely, causing the document to essentially scroll all the way to the top of the content. I'd like to actually stop the auto-scrolling once the user wheels. Is there a good pattern for this kind of setup? Any advice others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you could just remove `.scroll-down` class.

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("container");
    element.classList.remove("scroll-down");
   console.log(' * stop scrolling!');
});
```

Or with jQuery

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', () => {
    $("#container").removeClass('scroll-down');
    console.log(' * stop scrolling!');
});
```

Comment: This approach causes the page to scroll to the top of the content, but the goal is to retain the location to which the user has scrolled...